# vCard propagate with info from dB via php

Tags: php, vcf-vcard

Ok like a plonker I thought it would be easy as.

We have a popup with clients details in, to look like a vCard ( but heavily styled ) all propagated via our db on the fly.

So I just thought yeah no worries, we can use php within the vcard, and parse the relevant info .. so that wneh user clicks d/l link they get the correct vCard details..

Hmmm nope, and finding info about vCards etc is hard.

So here is a snippet of the vcard.vcf

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N;LANGUAGE=en-in:Name;Type;Your
FN:Type Your Name
TEL;WORK;VOICE:+1 (800) 123 4567
```

Example TEL is rendered in our php like: `<?=$r['tel'];?>`

So how do we get php within the vcard to make it useable.. any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is an example of a VCard file containing information for one person:

**vCard 2.1:**

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Gump;Forrest
FN:Forrest Gump
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
TEL;WORK;VOICE:(111) 555-1212
TEL;HOME;VOICE:            (404) 555-1212      
ADR;WORK:;;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;WORK;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:100 Waters Edge=0D=0ABaytown, LA 30314=0D=0AUnited States of   America
ADR;HOME:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;HOME;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:42 Plantation St.=0D=0ABaytown, LA 30314=0D=0AUnited States of America
EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:forrestgump@example.com
REV:20080424T195243Z
END:VCARD
```

**vCard 3.0:**

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Gump;Forrest
FN:Forrest Gump
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
PHOTO;VALUE=URL;TYPE=GIF:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:(111) 555-1212
TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:            (404) 555-1212      
ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;TYPE=WORK:100 Waters Edge\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America
ADR;TYPE=HOME:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
LABEL;TYPE=HOME:42 Plantation St.\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America
EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:forrestgump@example.com
REV:20080424T195243Z
END:VCARD
```

Once you have all your data in a formant you can use say a string variable :

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"vCard.vcf\"");
    echo $data;
?>
```

You can also if you wish create the file and off a link to that:

```
$ourFileName = "vCard.vcf";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

I hope this puts you on track and that I have understood your question correctly.

**ANSWER:**

```
<?php
    $vCard = "BEGIN:VCARD
    VERSION:3.0
    N:Gump;Forrest
    FN:Forrest Gump
    ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
    TITLE:Shrimp Man
    PHOTO;VALUE=URL;TYPE=GIF:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
    TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:(111) 555-1212
    TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:(404) 555-1212
    ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
    LABEL;TYPE=WORK:100 Waters Edge\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America
    ADR;TYPE=HOME:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
    LABEL;TYPE=HOME:42 Plantation St.\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America
    EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:forrestgump@example.com
    REV:20080424T195243Z
    END:VCARD";

    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"vCard.vcf\"");
    echo $vCard;
?>
```

The above code will allow the user to to download the vCard held in $vCard. In your case you would need to add your own data an example of how this would go is shown below:

```
    $vCard = "BEGIN:VCARD
    VERSION:3.0
    N:Gump;Forrest
    FN:Forrest Gump
    ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
    TITLE:".$array['title']."
    PHOTO;VALUE=URL;TYPE=GIF:".$array['weblink']."
    TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:".$array['WORKNUM']."
    TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:".$array['HOMENUM']."
    ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;".$array['Country']."
    LABEL;TYPE=WORK:100 Waters Edge\nBaytown, LA 30314\n".$array['Country']."
    ADR;TYPE=HOME:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;".$array['Country']."
    LABEL;TYPE=HOME:42 Plantation St.\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America
    EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:forrestgump@example.com
    REV:20080424T195243Z
    END:VCARD";
```

Comment: Not sure this answers my question, albeit seems to be very informative which I am very grateful. But. The issue is, we have a dynamic directory. On clicking a link, our vcard template opens in a modal ( in fact its just a template to look like a vcard ) .. but all the info we generate from our db to propagate that template. On that template we have a link, to download that persons vcard. 
The issue I have is how do I generate the vcard to import the db info for that person... ie. the persons details in the vcard.

Comment: Example: TITLE: Shrimp Man ( is our db entry for this person )
We generate that variable like <?=$r['title'];?>
So when user clicks Shrimp Mans ( example ) VCF link, the vcard propagates with all the data from our db for that particular person. In other words, can we pur variables ( php or other ) in the .vcf template, or must we generate something to produce the .vcf file on the fly ?

Comment: To be clear you can get all the ingormaiton you need for the VCF file (Title/Name/Teol  etc...) and you have this in various variables.

You can either create a file and keep it on your webserver or generate it dynamically for download by the user. I would recommend doing it dynamically.

Comment: To be clear you can get all the ingormaiton you need for the VCF file (Title/Name/Teol  etc...) and you have this in various variables.

You can either create a file and keep it on your webserver or generate it dynamically for download by the user. I would recommend doing it dynamically. 
You user would click on alink or dorp down and this would provide then with a file to download (the vCard).  You have a template for the vCard is this to show it on the website so the user can see the information and not download the vcard?  In the web viewable vCard you can PHP all you want.

Comment: In the Downloadable one you must have a file that sticks strictly to the vCARD standard no other text should be in it.

Comment: Yep, we have a template we have made, which is a mini site. Essentially, it includes all of a users information that you would ordinatily see on a vcard, and it looks vcard'ish. All of the information for that is generated dynamicaaly from our db and so we have a link on this template, allowing the user to download "this" vcard, and save etc... so just wanted to know how we can pass the variables to the vcf file. Thanks for sticking with this, appreciate your help.. we keep muddling away :)

Comment: OK i think i have your solution posted to the Origional Answer at the bottom. I tested it on my server to make sure ;)

Comment: cheers buddy, will check it out. Apologies been doing a flickr api lol. Will go check now and test this arvo. Voted best answer by the way albeit just you and me here :)

Comment: Thanks, sounds like you are on some fun projects. if u are on IM let me know.

Answer (score -2):

```
$vCard ="BEGIN:VCARD N:Mohammad Alam FN:Mohammad Alam BDAY:19910101 TEL;"
."HOME:+8801839095329 TEL;".
"CELL:+88001917579643 EMAIL:alam@datacenter.com.bd ".
"URL:www.yellowjobs.com.bd NOTE:Software Programmer(PHP,css codeigniter Framework"
.",Joomla,wordpress,zen cart) \nVisit : www.datacenter.com.bd\nvisit:"
." www.yellowjobs.com.bd\nwww.e vents365.com.bd \nI'm specialist Codeigniter Framework.".
" END:VCARD";
```